# Declare a class in inline-code in aspx/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I've got a self contained `aspx` script that now needs a small class for one function. Is there any way to declare a class in the code of this page without adding a code behind (`aspx.cs`) file?

I'd like to keep everything in one single file for neatness sake.

Comment: AFAIK if you simply don't have neither a CodeBehind nor a CodeFile attribute in your page, then all server side code is expected and supposed to go in the aspx file.

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question. All my code _is_ in the aspx file. I want to add more to it, but I can't see how

Comment: This sounds like you're starting with a solution in mind, and trying to fit it to the problem. You've got a hammer, so your problem looks like a nail. What are you trying to accomplish via this class? Maybe we can give you an easier way.

Comment: It's a newsletter opt-in form to go on several internal sites. As a single ASPX file I can drop it anywhere and link `<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.aspx"></script>`. AJAX loads a form which does callbacks to itself to validate, send out confirmation emails and confirm the subscription. It all works perfect, except that one tiny part of it requires JSON to be serialised to an object, which I couldn't get to work with anonymous types, hence I made a class with two string properties and serialised to that class instead. Have nail, need hammer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`I'd like to keep everything in one single file for neatness sake.` I fail to see how mixing code and markup could ever be neat. That being said, you could add the class inside of a `<script>` block, e.g: -

```
<script runat="server">
  public class MyClass
  {
     public static string Example()
     {
        Response.Write("Hello world");
     }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: no, it's not particularly readable, but from a file management point of view it is quite neat. I can drop that one file into a project and have it work.

Comment: From a management point of view, this will be hell when you want that class working on other pages as well.

Comment: Thanks Renan, but this is a guaranteed one-off. I only need it to convert JSON into an object on one page.

Comment: +1 I'd like to see more answers like that: (Q: "How to shoot yourself in the foot?" A: "You really shouldn't but here's how"). I hate when people answer with "You shouldn't want that. End of story.". Thanks again. ... Your sincere selffootshooter

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>

<script runat="server">
  public string OneFunction(string input)
  {
    return "It worked" + input;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are called Embedded Code Blocks, like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat=server>
protected String GetTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       Current server time is <% =GetTime()%>.
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```