# Structs and Classes not allowed in single page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Lets assume I have a single ASPX file with this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html>
  <body>
  <%
     int i = 5;
     Response.Write(i);
  %>
  </body>
</html>
```

After refresh the browser, I see the content of 'i' in the screen.

However, if I wrote that:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html>
  <body>
  <%
     struct S
     {
         public int i;
     }

     S a = new S();
     a.i = 5;
     Response.Write(a.i);
  %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the error:

```
 Line 18: a.i=5;
 CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.
```

The same happens if I replace the keyword 'struct' by 'class'.

I know the 'codefile' and 'codebehind' types of projects, but I'm curious why can't I declare structs and classes in one single ASPX file, just like in any C# program.

Can someone point me the reasons?

Thank you.

Comment: are you missing the public keyword?

Comment: @Infer-On,  It was a typo. The error happens with the public keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using a `script` element with `runat=server` specified:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat=server>
     struct S
     {
         public int i;
     }
</script>
<html>
  <body>
  <% 
     S a = new S();
     a.i = 5;
     Response.Write(a.i);
  %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result in doing so is you create a `private struct` inner to whatever class the ASPX is inheriting from, therefore it will be accessible anywhere on this page (but nowhere else).

Another example: [Declare a class in inline-code in aspx/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277074/declare-a-class-in-inline-code-in-aspx-c)

More info about using `script` embedded code blocks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx#Anchor_0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because the .aspx page is compiled as a class.

And when you have a code-behind class, you'll notice that it is marked as `partial`. The .aspx page and its code-behind class are both compiled as `partial` class with the same name.

I suspect that the contents of the .aspx is placed in a method and you cannot declare structs or classes inside a method.

Comment: "I suspect that the contents of the .aspx is placed in a method..." probably this is the reason of the error, because even though the .aspx page is compiled as a class, in any OO language I can declare nested classes (without deep level limit).